# Use Codable And Decodable in API Call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to call `API` using `Codable` and i want to access all `dictionary`, arrays from `API`.

Is This Possible from `codable`?

API Response eg:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "logo": "https://abc.png",
    "data": [
        {
            "crumb": {
                "Menu": {
                    "navigate": "Home",
                },
            },
            "path": "2",
            "type": "type0",
            "orientation": [
                {
                    "name": "All",
                }
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try before u ask is it possible ?

Comment: Yes i tried,                     if let jsonData = data11?.data(using: .utf8)
                        {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            let parsedData = try? decoder.decode(MainClassData, from: jsonData)
                            
                            print(parsedData!.name)
        
                            
                        }

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io is a great tool just for that. It will automatically generate all structs based on your json response. It's not perfect but it's a huge time saver when you're working with more complex api responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API response you've posted is invalid JSON (it has a bunch of trailing commas that make it illegal). This needs to be changed on the producer's side, and when you've done that, you can use this struct to access the data:

```
struct Entry: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let logo: String
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let crumb: Crumb
    let path, type: String
    let orientation: [Orientation]
}

struct Crumb: Codable {
    let menu: Menu

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case menu = "Menu"
    }
}

struct Menu: Codable {
    let navigate: String
}

struct Orientation: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```